# Testing website mailing locally

Tags: php, cakephp, localhost, mailing, mail-server

I'd like to test password recovery and similar email related features for a website.

I'm using PHP (cakePHP framework) and the syntax seems easy enough but I'm unsure of the email server setup.

I've looked around for a good tutorial but they aren't specific enough.

What is a quick and easy mail server to use locally? also... some initial steps to start up would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Test Mail Server Tool](http://toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/)

Answer (score 1):

xampp comes with a smtp server for sending mails from localhost, check out http://www.apachefriends.org

Answer (score 1):

I've had good success with [SMTP4DEV](http://smtp4dev.codeplex.com/) on a Windows box.  It is open source.

You can see recent messages fairly easily with this tool.  All it requires is that in your application you use localhost as the SMTP server.

Answer (score 0):

From what I remember PHP has a config file has a entry for the SMTP server. You can get a local SMTP server and point ini for PHP to localhost.
On Windows Microsft Internet Information Server would have SMTP, I think even client will have an SMTP relay (may not be a full server however). or I am sure you can find numeros free SMTP server.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at Post Case although I don't believe it is now (currently) free - it used to be, or you could look at Hamster 2.1 which is free, and then there is hMailServer 5.x.